# Using null assignment to control addition and removal of listeners

Tags: java, null, actionlistener

I have a case where a JComponent needs to have a listener added or removed depending on the state of other fields of a class. The listener should not be added more than once, and it can, of course, be removed only once. Is it a good practice to use a class field to store the listener and use the `null` value to control the action of registering/unregistering the listener with the Component.

The code I have in mind is something like this (code modified to make it clear that the JComponent is provided to the class):

```
public class MyClass {
  private ActionListener fListener = null;
  private JComponent fComponent;

  public MyClass(JComponent component) {
    fComponent = component; // for example, component = new JButton("Test");
  }

  public void setListener() {
    if (fListener == null ) {
      fListener = new MyListener();
      fComponent.addActionListener(fListener);
    }
  }

  public void removeListener() {
    if (fListener != null) {
      fComponent.removeActionListener(fListener);
      fListener = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not instantiate and dispose listener object every time. Use `getActionListeners()` method to verify that listener is added or not.

```
public class MyClass {
  private ActionListener fListener = new MyListener();
  private JButton fComponent = new JButton("Test");

  public MyClass() {
      fComponent.addActionListener(fListener);
  }
  public void setListener() {
    if (fComponent.getActionListeners().length == 0) {
       fComponent.addActionListener(fListener);
     }
  }

  public void removeListener() {
    if (fComponent.getActionListeners().length !=0) {
      fComponent.removeActionListener(fListener);
    }
  }
}
```

Method `ActionListener[] getActionListeners()` returns array of all the `ActionListeners` added to this `JButton`.

Comment: @AVD. The logic in your code would require that no other listener is added to the component than the one controlled by the `add/removeListener` methods, for which there is no guarantee in my application.  I will modify my example to make this situation more explicit.

Comment: @Kavka - Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Is it absolutely necessary to continually add and remove the listener from the component? Can you just disable the component, or have a flag that you can use to determine if the action can be run?

Can you wrap the listener in another listener that you define? The enveloping listener can have a boolean switch you can flip to control delegation to the real listener.

If worse comes to worst and you absolutely have to remove and add the listener, you can do it as follows, with a twist on AVD's solution:

```
public void setListener() {
    // java.util.List and java.util.Arrays
    List<ActionListeners> listenerList = Arrays.asList(fComponent.getActionListeners());

    if (!listenerList.contains(fListener) {
        fComponent.addActionListener(fListener);
    }
}

public void removeListener() {
    List<ActionListeners> listenerList = Arrays.asList(fComponent.getActionListeners());

    if (listenerList.contains(fListener) {
        fComponent.removeActionListener(fListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Having a flag to control the action in `actionPerformed' method of MyListener class seems like a viable alternative.